# How to send some arguments to the controller when user clicks the export button in yii2 kartik gridview?

Tags: php, gridview, export, yii2

I am using kartik gridview in yii2.. I have a form based on the values entered in the form I have shown the gridview..

There is a problem, When I added the export menu.. It will only call the controller .. So there is no data in file.

I want to pass some arguments to the controller when the user clicks the export button in kartik grid view..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In export params we can send values as a string using

```
       'exportRequestParam' => 'string',
```

in Export. If we want to send more than one values.. we should form a API then we should explode it.